# Zooming in on the python shell wing_ide

Tags: python, python-2.7, wing-ide

Is there any way to zoom in on the Python Shell in Wing IDE? I am having trouble seeing the font because it is too small.

Answer (score 1):

For Wing IDE:

Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseScrollUp</kbd> for quick changes. You can also just change your font size in the Editor preferences.

For Python IDLE:

Under Options --> Configure IDLE; change the Size.

For 'cmd' prompt or Bash:

Right-Click on the Window bar and select Properties. Change the font size in the 'Font' tab. If you want it to be permanent, do the same in 'Defaults' instead (from the right-click menu).

Comment: Ctrl+MouseWheel (or Command+MouseWheel on OS X) only works if the Editor > Enable Font Size Zooming preference is on.  I think it's off by default since it's too often inadvertently triggered.